# Check if picture in picture already exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webrtc, picture-in-picture

I am creating a picture in picture element that will be triggered as soon as the javascript files load.
Initially I would use a webcam stream as a video source, but upon a certain event change I would like to change the video source to a canvas element.
Is there a way to check whether a picture in picture element is already open in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

`document.pictureInPictureElement` will be video element if PIP available, else it will be `null`

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/picture-in-picture

```js
// Hide button if Picture-in-Picture is not supported.
pipButton.hidden = !document.pictureInPictureEnabled;

pipButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // If there is no element in Picture-in-Picture yet, let's request Picture
  // In Picture for the video, otherwise leave it.
  if (!document.pictureInPictureElement) {
    video.requestPictureInPicture()
      .catch(error => {
        // Video failed to enter Picture-in-Picture mode.
      });
  } else {
    document.exitPictureInPicture()
      .catch(error => {
        // Video failed to leave Picture-in-Picture mode.
      });
  }
  
  console.clear()
  console.log(!document.pictureInPictureElement)
});
```

```html
<button id="pipButton">Toggle PiP</button><br/>

<video id="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" width="50%"></video>
```

Comment: I don't think it's OP's concern so you had my upvote, but this method doesn't allow checking for an other PiP window open from other documents (which IIRC can still only be one)